# How to take only the integer items and calculate sum from the list?

Tags: python, django

Here i have list with product name and product price but i want to take only the products price from the list and calculate the total price of all products. How can i do it ?

```
For example i have a list:
all_products = ['food',1000,'pasta',500,'beer',400]
how can i do : 1000+500+400 = 1900
```

Comment: `sum(all_products[1::2])`? Have a look at the linked duplicate to better understand how slice notation works in python

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Filter out the integers and [sum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) them up

Comment: You can also do `sum(x for x in all_products if isinstance(x, int))` but if it always follows the pattern above, slicing will probably be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the integers are located on the odd indices, you can sum a slice of values, like:

```
sum(all_products[1::2])
```

but it might be better to take a look where you merge the two, and try to avoid that. For example by generating a list of 2-tuples, etc. Using a "flat" structure like the above one is usually not a good idea.

We can also sum up the `int`s and `float`s in the list, like:

```
sum(p for p in all_products if isinstance(p, (int, floats)))
```

But this is still "unsafe", since it is possible not all integers/floats are prices.

Comment: Well the solution depends on every odd indexed element being a number which might not be a general case

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh: well even filtering on numbers is not very safe. It would be better if it was a list of `Product`s for example, where we can fetch the `.price`. Since right now it is unsafe to assume all number-like objects are prices.

Comment: Yes but assuming it as a list of strings/numbers is much more closer than assuming it a list of objects

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh: well it is probably better to solve the problem "upstream", and avoid that. Since this is Django, it might even be possible to `.aggregate(..)`/`.annotate(..)` so to shift the computation to the database level, which is more efficient as well.

Comment: Wow, I did not see the django tag